# What's the explanation for the bolean output of this loop?

Tags: r, logic

I'm studying for an exam and this is one of the sample questions...

Can you run this code in your head and predict the output?

```
x=c(T,T,F,T,F)

for (i in 1:5){
  if(i > 1 & i < 5){
     x[i ] = x[i-1] & x[i+1] & x[i]

     print(x)
  }
}
```

I have interpreted this as... in the vector X for the values `(T[1],T[2],F[3],T[5],F[5])`... in other words for 
`(i in 1:5){if (i >1 & i <5)`
.... so for the values
 `T[2],F[3],T[4]`.... use this equation
`x[i ] = x[i-1] & x[i+1] & x[i]`
and print the value

given this statement the 1st and 5th position of the vector will stay the same, so [1] = T, and [5] = F.

Ok, x[2] = x[2-1] & x[2+1] & x[2] ; which would be T & F & T. given the Bolean logic this would give x[2] an output of False...

Now this also makes sense for x[3]
but when I get to x[4] I can't see why it's True

x[4] = x[3] & x[5] & x[4]; which is F & F & T... so it's still False... but the output I get is

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Can someone please explain this to me.

Comment: `x[4]` is false in the third printout, which is the one with `i=4` which assigns `x[4]`. Until then it is not changed.

Comment: Ohhhhh...... so the first print out is for all of the vector x when we use that equation on the 2nd position. Then the second print out is for the vector x when we use the equation on the 3rd position, while maintaining the equation from the first run through..... thank you.